# Read lambda from database and execute it

Tags: c#

I need to create a CSV mapping utility that allows a user to define a map from their CSV file to an internal class.  For instance, the user can map a `last_name` column to a `client.Lastname` property.

Many values will be simple -- string `last_name` to string `client.Lastname`.  Some will require a conversion that can be coded -- string `age` to int `client.age`.  However, some values require some translation.  For example a customer whose CSV values contain "A", "B" or "C" and another customer has "R","G" or "B" but the internal object uses values 1, 2 and 3.  In such a case I would need a routine for each customer similar to this:

```
string => {
   switch(string)
   {
       case "A":
          return 1;
       case "B":
          return 2;
       case "C"
          return 3;
       default:
          return 0;
    }
}
```

So, what I'd like to do is store that lambda expression with the map for the given field & customer in the map database.  Then read and execute that map transformation when converting a CSV for that customer.  So, pseudo code would look something like this:

```
//Read appropriate map for customer from map database
//For each row in CSV file
    //Read row
    //Create a new target object
    //For each column in column map
       //Find column in row -- string value = row[column]
       //If column has transformation, execute transform code -- var newvalue = map[column].transform(value);
       //Store value from column in target object property
```

I've looked at utilities like **CSVHelper** which allow for defining transformations -- the problem is, you have to know at design time what conversion is required and I'm trying to do it dynamically at run-time based on which customer is uploading a CSV.

Has anyone done anything like this?  Is there any way to store the transformation above (with the switch statement) as a string in a database, read it back in and execute it against a value?

**Clarification**
Essentially, each new customer we add to our system will come with their own CSV format -- we unfortunately don't have the luxury of forcing them to use a standard CSV format.  However, I also don't want to have to edit my code and add a new IF ...ELSE statement for each new client that knows how to convert their CSV data into our internal format -- I'd like to be able to somehow configure and store that in my internal mapping table.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq

Comment: I would not recommend storing executable code in the database. You should transform it before storing it.

Comment: @DanielA.White I may be missing it, but it seems this uses linq to simply serialize an object.  I'm wanting to store a linq statement that I can read and execute against a value to transform it into another value -- i.e. a linq statement that takes a string value of A and transforms that into a 3.

Comment: yes serialize linq appears to be a project that serializes expression trees and restores them for evaluations

Comment: So, I'm struggling with this.  My understanding is that an expression with a body cannot be converted into an Expression tree.  Serialize.Linq seems to serialize Expressions -- so how would I serialize my example above with the switch statement?

Comment: Restrict your mapping capabilities to expressions - you can replace `switch` with nested `?:` for example. Otherwise you step into the world of dynamic compilation (which there are plenty of articles about on the web).

Comment: C# will not convert a lambda with a statement body into an expression tree. There *are* "expression tree" classes for such bodies; they're used by the DLR I believe. But C# was never updated to use them because there was never a compelling high priority scenario that would justify doing the work.

Comment: Was "default" intended instead of "otherwise"?

Comment: @EricLippert yes, thanks, I've corrected that